# Why Xamarim Emulator is slower than android studio`s emulator? And how to make it quicker?

Tags: android, xamarin, android-emulator

I've made some test applications in Android Studio, and now I`m trying to work with Xamarim (I have a Mac).

The Android Emulator from Android Studio runs in a good speed. (It takes some time to start, but once started, the app itself runs ok.).

But Xamarin emulator seems to be very slow. The app runs on slow speed, it takes some time to respond to user actions.

How can i make Xamarim emulator run better, or make it use the same emultator from Android Studio.

Comment: The Xamarin Android Player is no longer supported.  You can use the standard Google Android Emulator with Xamarin instead.

Comment: You are not forced to use one specific emulator, you can use the ones Android SDK supplies, Genymotion, Xamarin Android Player, Visual Studio Emulators or whatever you want. As long as you can attach ADB to it. As @Jason mentions, Xamarin Android Player is not supported anymore. Why it is slow is probably due to you having multiple hypervisors on your machine, disallowing the currently running one from gaining hardware access.